# Not able to see Properties tab for Web Application project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-application-project

[image]

It must sound a stupid question but I am not able to find the "Properties" window so that i can set the IIS settings in my web application project. I am using Visual Studio 2010 (SP1). The weird thing is for other projects like a console application I am able to see the properties window.

Comment: Did highlighting the solution or the web project and hitting `F4` help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because that's a Visual Studio `Web Site`, not a Visual Studio `Project`.

When you create the site, choose `Project` instead, and after that you get to choose the project type, which can be one of the web types. Then you do get the properties tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `View menu` to get the properties window back Or got to `Windows => Reset Window Layout` if you need to reset them back.